# Jenkins multi-branch pipeline missing a branch

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins system.  It runs build jobs for our company. We run multibranch pipelines. Yesterday one of the builds mysteriously dropped the devel branch from the build.

I looked through the Pull Requests for the branch and I can not find anything that affected by the Jenkins file in the time frame where this branch drop occurred.

I have looked through the Jenkins system log and I do not see any errors. Here is a copy of the relevant parts of the scan repository log:

```
Examining Bo**a/pro-***-ter

  Checking branches...

  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch devel

  Getting remote pull requests...

    Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
```

I have validated that the devel branch has a Jenkinsfile and that the Jenkinsfile is valid.

I can't figure out how to solve this.  Any suggestions would be great.

Some plugin information:

- github 1.28.0
- branch 2.0.11
- docker-common 1.13
- docker-pipeline 1.17
- git 3.6.0
- git client 2.7.0
- git server 1.7
- SCM API 2.2.3

Jenkins version 2.73.2

Comment: Did you check the configuration ?? maybe someone modified the Behaviors and ignored the devel branch

Comment: What do you mean by modify the behaviors?

Comment: Under the MultiJob, there is a configure option where you generally mention the GitHub/SVN connection and along with that the Behavior/Discovery of branches

Comment: same problem here. After `Met criteria` the log says
`Detected unsupported subitem repo » develop, skipping` - Have you figured out yet how to solve this problem?

Comment: @cornr where did you find the log ?
I have a similar problem. Randomly a branch disappeared from a new multi-branch pipeline job, every other branch does appear fine. There's no change in  branch discovery configuration.

Comment: @coding_idiot you can find the log in "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log" within your project.

Comment: FWIW: [JENKINS-55220](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55220)

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem with BitBucket Server and Jenkins when using Blue Ocean (BitBucket Server plugins). The branch would not create in Jenkins. I noticed that the branch commit and the pull request (PR) had a successful build. It seems that if Jenkins detects a PR is opened for a branch, it will not create the branch on the Jenkins side. Once I deleted the pull request from BitBucket Server, Jenkins registered the branch and it showed up. Would be better if the branch showed up, had no builds and referenced the Pull request Jenkins job!

Comment: This was particularly confusing and annoying when `develop` vanished in Jenkins just because a PR from `develop` to `master` was open. The behaviour can be changed in the job settings.

Comment: Discover Branches > All Branches (instead of Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for taking so long to answer this:
I did a plugin upgrade to the latest version of all of the plugins in my Jenkins. 
 That solved my issue.

Comment: something similar worked for me as well. There was no error or valuable information in the `scan log`.

Answer (score 0):

I think we might found an answer (or problem causer).
In our case we automatically restarted Jenkins once a day in either in the shut down or boot up process branches went missing.

The amount of missing branches declined significantly after keeping the Jenkins running all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Detected unsupported subitem repo » develop, skipping
In my case I just deleted the develop pipeline(by clicking its link on scan branch log page) and rescan, all worked.
It seems while performing scan it probably point to an obsolete hash in Git preventing Jenkins job to scan correctly.